# VS Code does not detect AVD

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-virtual-device

I try to test a flutter project created in VS code on a virtual device. The AVD starts normal, but it isn't detected in VS Code.

I tried all re-install avd, reinstall flutter and darf extensions, reinstall flutter.

On start of VScode always a message appears "The dart server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes."

VSCode always shows "No Device", when i click on "No Device" the popup "Select a deivce" appears but didn't display something to select.